# ngrx store - Update an array properly.

Tags: c#, arrays, angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm using ngrx/store in my app and I'm having trouble saving an array. My array is set to empty at startup with:

```
export interface AppState{
    customObjects: Array<CustomObject>;
};

export const initialState: AppState = {
    customObjects: []
};
```

and I am trying to manually feed it an array of two CustomObjects using the following function:

```
loadCustomObjects() {
    let initialItems: CustomObject[] = [
        {
            directoryName: "d_name_1",
            brokenLinks: 0,
        },
        {
            directoryName: "d_name_2",
            brokenLinks: 0,
        }
    ];

    this.appStore.dispatch({ type: LOAD_CUSTOM_OBJECTS, payload: initialItems });
}
```

Calling this function dispatches a call to my reducer function:

export const mainReducer: ActionReducer = (state: AppState, action: Action) => {

```
if (typeof state == 'undefined') {
    state = initialState;
}

switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_CUSTOM_OBJECTS:
        return Object.assign({}, action.payload)
    default: {
        return state;
    }
}
```

}

This all seems fine, but my main app component's array does not get the two objects. If I manually set the default state to have those two CustomObjects, then it works (I can't do this since I need to be able to update the array whenever I want). My HomeComponent uses:

```
customObjects$ Observable<Array<CustomObject>>;

constructor(private appStore: Store<AppState>) {
            appstore.select('mainReducer')
            .subscribe((data: AppState) => {

                if (typeof data != 'undefined') {
                    this.customObjects$ = Observable.of(data.customObjects);
                }
            });
}
```

I've analyzed my objects and I expect to see 'this.customObjects$' end up being an array of two CustomObjects. Instead, it is a ScalarOservable:

ScalarObservable {_isScalar: true, value: undefined, scheduler: null}, etc. etc.

Note - I'm not sure if I need to, but I have included ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush in my home component's @Component section. I've also made sure to use

```
StoreModule.provideStore({ mainReducer })
```

in my app.module class.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and why 'this.customObjects$' is not a two object array? I'm new to ngrx/store - I get the feeling there is an issue with the way my reducer function is setting the array but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work with this code:

Store related code:

```
export interface CustomObject {
  directoryName: string;
  brokenLinks: number;
}

export interface AppState {
  Main: CustomObject[];
};

export function MainReducer(state: CustomObject[] = [], action: Action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_CUSTOM_OBJECTS:
      return Object.assign({}, action.payload);
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}

const reducers = {
  Main: MainReducer
};
```

Component/Service to dispatch/listen to store

```
customObjects: CustomObject[];

constructor(private appStore: Store<AppState>) {
  appStore.select(store => store.Main)
    .subscribe(objs => {
      this.customObjects = objs;
      console.log(this.customObjects);
    })
}


loadCustomObjects() {
  let initialItems: CustomObject[] = [
    {
      directoryName: "d_name_1",
      brokenLinks: 0,
    },
    {
      directoryName: "d_name_2",
      brokenLinks: 0,
    }
  ];

  this.appStore.dispatch({ type: LOAD_CUSTOM_OBJECTS, payload: initialItems });
}
```

Async pipe version:

```
customObjects$: Observable<CustomObject[]>;

constructor(private appStore: Store<AppState>) {
  this.customObjects$ = appStore.select(store => store.Main);
}


loadCustomObjects() {
  let initialItems: CustomObject[] = [
    {
      directoryName: "d_name_1",
      brokenLinks: 0,
    },
    {
      directoryName: "d_name_2",
      brokenLinks: 0,
    }
  ];

  this.appStore.dispatch({ type: LOAD_CUSTOM_OBJECTS, payload: initialItems });
}

<div *ngFor="let customObj of customObjects$ | async"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason your component's customObjects array is NOT an observable?

Comment: It depends on how you want to use it.  If you plan on using the async pipe, you can use the observable directly instead of manually subscribing to it.  https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: With your code, customObjects never updates for me, which is why I'm trying to use an observable. Whenever I use an observable, I at least see updates, however, customObjects is updated to become a ScalarObservable, instead of a two object array.

Comment: Whenever you do appStore.select(store => store.Main) it returns an observable.  I just have it immediately subscribe to the observable.  Anyway if you are binding the observable directly to the UI you can use the async pipe version, I updated my answer with that approach as well.

Comment: This video does a good job explaining the async pipe: https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-2-using-the-async-pipe-in-angular-2

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it out. Out of curiosity, what typescript and node.js versions are you using? I've been looking at countless ngrx/store examples and there are several things that just flat out do not work/compile for me. For example, I cannot do optional parameters in my reducer function - I always get a syntax error. I'm wondering if my troubles with ngrx/store are related to something in my project that ngrx store's docs fails to mention.

Comment: I tested the code and it's own this branch as reference for you: https://github.com/seescode/budget/tree/feature/stack-overflow

I'm using node 7.7.0 and typescript ~2.2.2.  I generally just steal the package.json settings from the example app so I don't deal with the dependency headaches: https://github.com/ngrx/example-app